# How to prevent `package.json` beign rewritten by `npm update`

Tags: npm, npm-update

Let's say I have a dependency in my `package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "my-dependency": "~1.0.0"
  }
```

And there's `1.0.1` version of the package available. When I run `npm update my-dependency` it changes the version in `package-lock.json` file to 1.0.1 (which is completely fine) and it changes the dependency in `package.json` to

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "my-dependency": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

Why? How to prevent it? I only wanted to change my `package-lock.json` file, I didn't want to change `~` to `^`.